# The type or namespace name 'OleDb' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#

I am using visual studio 2015  and I get these error messages :

> Error CS0234 The type or
>   namespace name 'OleDb' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data'
>   (are you missing an assembly reference?)**

and

> Error CS0234 The type or
>   namespace name 'SqlBulkCopy' does not exist in the namespace
>   'System.Data.SqlClient' (are you missing an assembly reference?)**

when I use `System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader` and `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy` but it works fine in visual studio 2013.

Can someone help ?

How do I use this these two references in Visual Studio 2015 ?

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve]. Start with Visual Studio open with no solution. Step 2 should be creating a new project, but you need to tell us which template you're working with.

Comment: If you look at the MSDN documentation for those two classes, then you'll see that they are in `System.Data.dll`. Make sure you have a reference to that dll in your project.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the assembly reference of `System.Data` in your project like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for helping me, I am developing a single page web application on asp.net5, I added that reference but it is still giving me an error  message.

Comment: @AMohlala:- Can you share the code from where you are getting the error?

Comment: I am trying to share the code but I can't post it says  a comment is too long.

Comment: @AMohlala - don't try to put code in comments. [**edit**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35171459/edit) your question instead.